# How to run command in to another command?

Tags: command-line

How to run command in to another command?

Example

```
curl 123+echo shuf 100-999 -n 1+blabla.html
```

so that end would be random

```
curl 123999blabla.html
curl 123111blabla.html
curl 123000blabla.html
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you should be able to capture the output of the command using `$(command ...)` and then loop over the values, e.g.

```
for i in $(shuf -i 100-999 -n10); do curl "123${i}blabla.html"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

How many url?

For a single url

```
curl 123$((RANDOM%1000+100))blabla.html
```

for more then one, you need a loop as steeldriver indicated